# Choosing between unity and native java for a game that involves complex Android functions

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, 2d-games, android-unity-plugin

I want to develop a game for Android that involves using the camera, reading files on the device, reading contacts, etc.

Can I perform these operations if I use unity for development or will I have to go with native java?
Or can I start off with unity and then import the project into Android studio and then add those features?

The game would be a story based game. So it's just 2D with a low poly art style.

(I have quite a bit of experience with app development but this is my first time trying to develop a game.)

Comment: There are native android plugins on the store some of them are free. Like you can't access to gallery directly in Unity. You need to create your own plugin or find one on the store. Other than that, it's just based on your experience. I know Unity better than Android Studio, so i use Unity even for small apps that can be done easily in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a broad question because there are pros and cons against both. Unity is a powerful game engine and can be used for all kinds of games but if you want to do stuff like reading contacts, you'll have to write your own plugin to connect the native android.

There are examples of such plugins [here](https://github.com/aliessmael/Unity-Contacts-List)

But you'll really have to do more investigation yourself.